# Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox not creating SSLKEYLOGFILE to be used by wireshark

Tags: firefox, encryption, ssl, wireshark, tls

One should be able create an SSL Pre-Master-Secret key log file from firefox by creating the environment variable `export SSLKEYLOGFILE=~/path/to/sslkeylog.log` so external programs, i.e. Wireshark, are able to decrypt ssl/tls packages. [This](https://www.m00nie.com/2015/05/decrypt-https-ssltls-with-wireshark/) page mentions that the feature was broken in firefox 48 but from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format) it should have been fixed in Firefox >= 50. I'm using Firefox 54 that comes default in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Has anyone got this working in Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Firefox developer edition or recompile firefox with trace and debug options.

Comment: Could you add some details on how to do this (and/or a source)?

Comment: You can download here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition

Uncompress and execute it. You can use SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable.